# Passing data from UIView Controller textField to a TableViewController Label on a cell- Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I pass textField data from a UIView Controller text field to a tableview label in a cell? I would like to somehow add the textfield data to an Array so that I can set the number of rows return value to the arrays count.

I've added an NSMutable array to my model.

In my view controller I'm implementing the prepareForSegue method

```
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"]){

        MileageDetailViewController * mdv = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSString *text;
        startTextField.text = text;
        mdv.label.text = text;
```

I've tried this several different ways. I've done this with an array and tried to add text object an array but that didn't display either. This last way I tried using a label and adding the text from textField to a tableview Label.

```
 In the tableView I add this code to grab the text from the viewController.

     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    { 
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Reuse"];

    UILabel *labe = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:20];

    labe.text = label.text;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
```

Comment: I recommend following some of the free tutorials on Ray Wenderlich's site (http://www.raywenderlich.com); these will show you the MVC pattern, probably answer your question and improve your Objective-C skills.

Comment: Thanks, I've followed tutorials from there and I know how to pass data from tableView to another tableview. I'm using an mvc but i'm having trouble passing the information to the tableview. I'll put some code up so you can see what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your first paragraph? Why would you transfer text from a UIViewController text field to a tableview label in a cell? The cell contents should come from the model backing the tableview (usually an NSArray).  Please can you clean up your question with your exact problem and clarify where the prepareForSegue comes into the question. Do you have two problems: 1) How to store and display data in a UITableView and 2) How to pass data to another View Controller?

Comment: The first screen of the app is a UIViewController. It has a textField on this screen for user input. The user inputs a number in the textField, the next screen the user inputs a description in another UITextField and I wanted to save the data into a UITableView. If I enter 356 in the textField I want to save that number in a table view label cell. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible (but strange, why not just have a tableview with an "add" button that prompts for the info and adds a new row); but that's too much code to write without writing the app for you. I'll have a think if there's some examples I can put down for you tomorrow (it's late here).

Comment: Thank you, The only reason I'm doing it this way is because I have a view with a UIImage and the label inside the image which looks really good and I figured it wouldn't look good on a table. I figured I would gather the info and just save it to the table like a summary.

Comment: I meant textField, not label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code examples below are just to get you started.  But I strongly, strongly recommend you follow the tutorials on Ray Wenderlich's site ([link](http://www.raywenderlich.com)) as you seem to just be starting on iOS development.

Passing data between view controllers using `prepareForSegue:` (with comments in code block):

```
// This will get called before the view appears
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Details"]) {
        // Get destination view controller
        MileageDetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Grab the text field contents and put it into a public property on the new view controller
        vc.myText = self.myTextField.text;
        // NOTE: myText is a public NSString property on your MileageDetailViewController
        // NOTE: self.myTextField is the IBOutlet connected to your Text Field
    }
}
```

Now onto the methods in your controller with the table view:

```
// Load the model required for the view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load your "model" - in this case an array property (called myData) with a single piece of text
    // NOTE: myText CANNOT be nil or an exception will occur
    self.myData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: self.myText, nil];
}


// UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{ 
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  [self.myData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    // NOTE: You must have set the reuse identifier in Interface Builder for this to work
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Reuse"];

    // NOTE: You must have set the tag in Interface Builder for this to work
    UILabel *labe = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:20];

    labe.text = [self.myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps; iOS development is a lot of fun but following some tutorials will really help you get up-to-speed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with the code. Your example code helped me understand the process even more and I really appreciate the time that you took out to complete this for me.

Comment: I have everything how you explained and still no data in the table view. Weird

Comment: my tag has been set to 20 and my segue is set to Details

Comment: I set an nslog in the tableView controller viewDidLoad and the value I get back from the textField is null

Comment: I set another NSLog in the prepare for segue and I get the value of the textField but it seems after the segue has completed the data becomes null

Comment: You should post another question, with your source code (including your header files), and a description of the problem.  It's the only way as this question is too complex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get comfortable with the MVC design pattern.  Create a model class that holds the array.  When the text field is modified, update the array.  If the table view's view controller is observing the same model object (perhaps using KVO) then it can auto-update when the array changes.